# Annoying dual-screen window placement issues

Tags: display

Generally most things work well for me on 5.1, but I have one annoying issue.

I have an external monitor connected to my laptop via HDMI, and have it set as my primary screen (to the right of my laptop). When I open almost anything (File Manager, Code, etc) it opens first on the laptop screen, but so high that the top of the window is off-screen and no matter what I do I can't move it.

Open another instance of said application and it opens on the external screen as I'd expect. Closing the laptop is an option, but a waste of a screen.

Both screens are 1920 x 1080 resolution, and graphics are Intel or a GTX785M card.

Comment: This is not a solution, but as temporary help for the windows stuck too high: By holding down the Command (also known as Super or Windows) key you can left-click and hold a window from any spot and move it with the mouse.

Comment: Not a fix, but thanks for the suggestion - it'll get me out of trouble for now